# How would I create a temp table in SQL Server when I have a big list of ID's

Tags: sql-server, database, temp-tables

I have a list of raw IDs that I am supposed to put into a temp table. I am unsure about how this works in SQL Server:

I know the general format:

```
select PID into #myPIDs
from ... ?
```

I already have a list of about 30 PIDs which I am to use. They look like so:

```
'U388279963',
'U388631403',
'U389925814'
```

How do I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Are the PIDs in another table, a comma-delimited variable, a set of variables, hard-coded, something else?

Comment: Hey , so they're hard-coded. I have a text file with them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your format will work for creating a new temp table for one insert.  If you need to copy and paste your IDs then the following will work.

```
CREATE TABLE #myPIDs
(
     PID VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO #myPIDs
VALUES
(....),
(....);
```

Copy and paste your PIDs and use find and replace with regular expressions to replace each line with the regular expression option checked.  Remove the last ',' and you're good.

> Find - ^{U:z+}$
>
> Replace - ('\1'),\n

Alternatively you can have sql server read your ids from a file on the system.  If you elaborate on your needs I can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
insert into #myPIDs (ID) 
select 'U388279963'
union 
select 'U388631403'
union 
select 'U389925814'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you original table (from witch comes IDs) is accessible and always have a row with each ID :

```
SELECT originalTable.ID
INTO #myPIDs
FROM originalTable
WHERE originalTable.ID IN ('U388279963', 'U388631403', 'U389925814')
```