# Remove rows where id not in (very large) list - Best practice?

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering what the best practice would be, when you have a large list of id's, and you need to delete rows that do not include an id in the list.

It seems to me like the way to go is using the "not in" feature:

```
DELETE FROM Foo  
WHERE ID NOT IN (1, 2, 3,... 20000)
```

But I'm not sure how performance compliant this solution is, when your list is pretty large.

Any suggestions on how to do it otherwise?

Comment: Fill a temp table

Comment: ..and use not exists?

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate?

Comment: DELETE a FROM Foo a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tbl_temp WHERE id_temp = a.id);

Comment: which format do you have this list of integers in. Do you have it in a string variable or XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create and fill a temp table and then use `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(id INT)

INSERT #foo VALUES(1)
INSERT #foo VALUES(2)
INSERT #foo VALUES(3)
INSERT #foo VALUES(4)
INSERT #foo VALUES(5)
INSERT #foo VALUES(6)
INSERT #foo VALUES(20000)

WHILE @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN 
   DELETE TOP (100) FROM Foo WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #foo f WHERE f.Id = Foo.ID )
END
```

Related: [How would I create a temp table in SQL Server when I have a big list of ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11958710/284240)

Comment: why while loop?

Comment: @Amit: not needed, just a way to delete in batches if the table is so large

Comment: Make sure that there is index, or even better, primary key in the temp table.

Comment: could you not also use a loop to fill in the "where ID not in (1, 2, ...)' so you would keep the "not in ()" always limited to max 100 id's ?